# MS Access Report: How to add a line break in a text box based on the text displayed

Tags: ms-access, report, line

I am not at all good with Access VB coding. I want to add a line break in a text box based on the value. I am importing a text box from an outside source that has data for different weeks in the same field. "Week of 1/1/19: lorem ipsum Week of 1/8/19: lorem ipsum" I want to use this as one field in my report and I want to create a line break for every week, please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:

```
Mid(Replace([ImportedField], "Week ", vbCrLf & "Week "), 3)
```

It will return:

```
Week of 1/1/19: lorem ipsum 
Week of 1/8/19: lorem ipsum
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you. I tried using this expression and got an error message that states that the object doesn't contain the Automation object 'vbCrLf'.

Comment: Hello, Thank you again, I tried again and it worked!